# SQL filter on Date doesn't work

Tags: sql, automationstudio, datetime

In my Data Extension I have a column named 'CreatedDate'. This is formatted like this: Wednesday, May 03, 2023 9:20 AM

In my automation I want to select only records since 01/01/2023. Time parameter doesn't matter.
I have tried numerous variations with Convert functions, style codes ... but I keep getting "Could not convert date and/or time from string data type."

I have no possibility (at the moment) to change the style code in my source data extension.

Can anyone help me configuring this sql query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this particular function in SFMC, but it can parse the date string in that format:

```sql
select parse('Wednesday, May 03, 2023 9:20 AM' as datetime) parsedDate
```

| parsedDate |
| --- |
| 2023-05-03 09:20:00.000 |

Try it yourself: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nN-Y8g2Z)

**EDIT**: It is valid in a Query Activity

[image]